# callback page doesn't load any js or css files

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension need to use oauth in options.html, once it success in getting oauth token, the server will callback options.html and pass the token. This system work well in windows's chrome(version:22.0.1229.94), but in mac osx(chrome version:21.0.1180.89), the call back page(options.html) doesn't load any js or css file.
It will be very appreciated for helping me out.

My server use .net. Once it get oauth token from evernote, application redirect to url:
chrome-extension://libhbnapikdkkfhfkmpjnpgcapfnfljd/options.html?oauth=xxxxxxxx
and then, it will open options.html. but in mac osx, the page can't load any js or css files.
In windows,it work well.

my options.html is very simple, and load files below:

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tools.js"></script>
<script src="js/options.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700|Sanchez|Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/options.css" />
```

Comment: sharing your code can get us more visibility of problem.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.The adding content make problem clearly?

Comment: can you share options.html and it's related js files?